# Freely Available Datasets/APIs?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, artificial-intelligence

I've been studying algorithms about collective intelligence, for things such as recommendation engines, neural networks etc., and was looking for freely available datasets and/or APIs for practice projects. any suggestions?

Here are some examples of the types of things I was looking for:

[Delicious API](http://delicious.com/help/api): collection of links, tags, who liked them, etc.

[Ebay API](http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/): resource of various items, prices, descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the UCI Machine Learning Repository is what you're looking for.

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

[Weka's](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) website (a collection of Machine Learning algorithm) also features a list of datasets:

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index_datasets.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the largest single body of gathered AI knowledge was/is Cyc. You can download [OpenCyc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencyc/), which includes a data set of millions of hand-entered ontological assertions about the Real World (e.g. "water is wet").

There's also a metric boatload of code, both in C and Lisp, to work with that data.